# Unit testing Burstly Activity (Android)

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, burstly

I've tried following two approaches for Unit testing a custom activity that extends BurstlyActivity:

1. Using Robolectric. It fails at multiple places where its looking for Burstly related layouts and Burstly specific classes, which may not present in robolectric framework
2. Using Android Unit Testing. It gives this error:

> java: MyActivityTest.java:14: cannot access com.burstly.lib.conveniencelayer.BurstlyActivity
>   class file for com.burstly.lib.conveniencelayer.BurstlyActivity not found

My question is: How can I unit test my app which uses/extends Burstly? If anyone have done such thing in past then your experiences and learnings will be very useful.

Comment: When you use robolectric what are errors you are seeing ?Are they related to the AndroidManifest.xml file?